# grey background on responsive IPhone

Tags: html, css

I really do not get this. I am making a landingpage:

[Landingpage](http://vouzalis.com/landingpage)

If I look the responsive design on Iphone 5, 6 and 6+, there is a grey background behind the logos. It is also appearing under the form. The background image should go to the top. I have been looking through the code for hours, but cannot find the answer. Can anybody see why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `.fullscreen {background-size:cover;}`

The grey background you see is just the body color because your background image doesn't take the whole space.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Works perfect :)